# synonym for a "request to join"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Given a group of people and a person, if the group asks the person to join, the group "invites" the person, or sends "invitation." If the person requests to join the group, what is a word (preferably single-word) that means this, either in verb or noun form?

I have considered the following:

- self-invite: accurate, but is a two-word phrase and too colloquial
- impose/imposition: single-word, somewhat accurate, carries negative connotation
- appeal: single-word without connotation, but not very accurate

Comment: I am having trouble with the single-word requirement. Even the word invite only implies an invitation to join by the context in which it is used.

Comment: @BobbiBennett single-word isn't a hard-requirement but is preferred (I have just made a post edit to say this)

Comment: Hi. Please note the request under the single-word request tab link: *To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*

Answer (score 3):

**apply**

e.g. apply for a job.

"to make an appeal or request especially in the form of a written application"
(Merriam-Webster)

(ETA: formatting and example)

Comment: (+1) I think this is a good answer and very accurate for situations involving a formal process to acquire membership

Answer (score 0):

You can **apply** to join a group or you can **request** or **make a request** to join.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **apply** to join she can

- **Insert** herself into the group
- **Slide** into their DM's (colloquial)
- **Petition** to join the group
- **Join** the group
- **Expand** the group